# Magnets: amplifying a magnetic beam - concern of weakening over time

Tags: magnetic-fields

We have a specific requirement to concentrate a magnetic beam using small Neodymium Magnets.

Came across several older threads and within those, an older -now expired- patent:
https://patents.google.com/patent/US5929732

I am about to test this out, to see if it fulfills our requirements, but I am concerned that the arrangement of the 5 magnets (see picture) will cause the Neodymium Magnets to weaken prematurely over time.

Question: would this arrangement of 5 small disk-shaped Neodymium Magnet be cause for demagnetization?

[image]

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. No one seems to know the answer to this.